# branches on same line as master in network view

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have a small problem using github.
I mainly try to work with branches, and merge code back in the master as soon as I have something working.

Thing is, all my branches in the network view in github show up on the same line, which makes it completely useless. 
https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/network

Can you explain me the reason for that?

When creating a branch locally, It does not show up automatically in github.
When I perform a

```
git push -u origin master
```

It shoes up, but on the same line as the master.

What confuses me is that on my other projects, I don't have this problem, without really knowing what I did differently.
https://github.com/jlengrand/FaceMovie/network

Any help would be really appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merge a branch back to master with no commits hapening on master since you created the branch, it doesn't create a merge commit (i.e. a commit with two parents), but rather it fast-forwards the master branch to the other.

To prevent this, use `--no-ff` option when merging. This will force the merge commit.

Comment: You might add that many developers prefer the linear history that the OP is seeing as it helps understand the development flow.

Comment: Works fine indeed. I still don't get the difference between my two repos though, as I never used this option before.